# Kong Gateway replace response status code

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

I have seen both the [Response Transformer Plugin](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/response-transformer/) and the [Advanced Response Transformer Plugin](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/response-transformer-advanced/) that will allow you to change, for example, the body of a particular response, for example by setting the declarative way:

```
config.replace.body='{\"error\": \"internal server error\"}'"
```

How could I change the status code of a response, for example if I wanted to always return 200 even when other plugins such as the rate limiter one intercept the request?

Is there another plugin that may support this functionality? Or should I write a custom plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way is to use the serverless-function plugin: https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/serverless-functions/ in particular the `post-function` plugin.

This plugin allows you to apply a custom lua function, runned after the other plugins, e.g. to the kong response. To change the status code you could use something like:

```
        return function()
           kong.response.set_status(200)
        end
```

and apply this snippet of code to the `header_filter` phase (a parameter of the plugin conf.).

Another possibility is to use the `exit-plugin` https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/exit-transformer/ to change the Kong's response.